# Clear previous value of a TextView

Tags: android, textview

So I have a TextView to display the result I have to it. I need that when I press the button second time or I press a different button to clear the current value displayed by the TextView and show the new one. But what I get is that new text is showed on top of the old value.

Here is how I try to do this:

```
//first button press
TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
tw.setText("");
tw.setText("Test 1 = " + result1);
tw.invalidate();
//second button press
TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
tw.setText("");
tw.setText("Result = " + result1);
tw.invalidate();
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Use one TextView instance for showing value on both button clicks.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:

```
TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);  //globally declared
//first button press
tw.setText("Test 1 = " + result1);

//second button press
tw.setText("Result = " + result1);
```

[setText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType%29) sets the text of a textview, means the old text is already discarded with its call.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem was in emulator. Deploying to device works fine. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for this

```
TextView tw;    //declare globally

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourScreen);
         tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
         tw.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tw.setText("Test 1 = " + result1);
            }
        });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
//in onCreate
TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
//first button press
tw.setText("Test 1 = " + result1);
//second button press
tw.setText("Result = " + result1);
```